# WEBKIT date.getTime() calculation

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to calculate difference in days between two JS dates.
I had a function which worked fine in Firefox:

```
function timeDiffDays(date01,date02){
    return Math.abs(Math.ceil( (date01.getTime() - date02.getTime()) /1000/60/60/24 ));
}

 date01=2013/11/06              //Wed 6th November 2013
 date02=2013/11/04              //Mon 4th November 2013
```

FF:

date01 = 1383741491140; date02 = 1383568691000;

So final difference in days: 2.0000016203703703, with Math.ceil()= correct 3

But in Safari (WEBKIT):

date01=1383741564156; date02=1383568764156;

Final difference in days: 2, with Math.ceil() = wrong 2

To get around it, I had to jig hours, minutes and seconds of passed dates:

```
date01.setHours(12);date01.setMinutes(11);date01.setSeconds(10);
date02.setHours(12);date02.setMinutes(5);date02.setSeconds(11);
```

If they are set explicitly the same, or just 1 second difference, result comes wrong.
Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Calculate the differeence in seconds and then convert to hour min or day

Comment: Or use [1][moment.Js]
[1]http://momentjs.com/

Comment: the right result is 2, not 3.